Setup - Flutter + Android Studio + WSL2 (ubuntu)
TLDR -> I need to find a way to install flutter, dart, android studio on a windows machine with WSL2
My setup

Windows 10
WSL2 with Ubuntu
VSCode installed on windows (connected to WSL)
Ruby and Ruby on rails installed on ubuntu

So my dev environment is used on ubuntu for now
I would like to learn dart + flutter and use it on my ubuntu environement
Setup I want to add

dart + flutter installed on ubuntu
android studio installed on windows

WSL2 use the virtualization that's why I installed android studio on windows (emulators)
Problem
➜  ~ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS 5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android SDK file not found: adb.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

➜  ~ adb devices
List of devices attached
127.0.0.1:5555  device
emulator-5554   device

➜  ~ flutter devices
Found 2 connected devices:
  Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS 5.15.167.4-microsoft-standard-WSL2
  Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 131.0.6778.85

adb launcher (adb.exe) can't be used in wsl so flutter devices can't detect my android studio emulator
I tried many ways but impossible to find a way to develop my app on ubuntu and use my emulator from android studio on windows
Is there anybody with any tutorial to tell me if there is a way and how to setup dart, flutter, android studio and vscode on my machine ?

Why do you need wsl? All of these tools are available for ubuntu, I think you have to install android studio on wsl too. I'm not sure, I don't see why would one use a setup like this for flutter development.

@CsabaMihaly i tried to install android studio on wsl but wsl is already using the virtualization, so I can't use any emulator is this case

I'm thinking that i just need to install all my development setup on windows... (i would avoid it because i already have one on ubuntu for ruby etc...)

You should start the emulator on windows, on linux you need studio for the build. But you are just making your life harder, either go full Linux or windows, sure it's possible to use wsl. I just don't see why you want this.

@CsabaMihaly as I told, avoiding to have 2 development environments on my machine

Just a clarification between Dart and Flutter, as you imply something about it, which seems to have needed some attention.

You do not need to install Dart separately as the Flutter SDK includes
the full Dart SDK.

To learn more.
Additional tips: You can also use VS Code, but it is recommended to install Android Studio for some development reasons.

Yes thanks, indeed I just mention dart & flutter in the message but your true ;)
